# Java doesn't read correctly an excel file and it doesn't identify correctly vars

Tags: java, excel

I am doing app with SpringBoot (java) and I want read the excell, but when show datas the excel, the years is incorrect , and the input "boolean" in excell show String in java.

The momento I put the path hardcore.

Controller

```
@ApiOperation("Upload XLSX file")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/insert", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MyMessage create(@RequestBody MultipartFile multipart) {

try {
    InputStream multipartFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\emartinp\\Desktop\\Nominacion.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(multipartFile);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Header header = sheet.getHeader();

    int rowsCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println("Total Number of Rows: " + (rowsCount + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        int colCounts = row.getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("Total Number of Cols: " + colCounts);
        for (int j = 0; j < colCounts; j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println("es num" + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.println("es string" + cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println("boolean" + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
            }
            // System.out.println("[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error  " + ex);
} finally {

}

return null;

}
```

My excell:
[image]

Result

[image]

You can see that type boolean in excell in java is type String...
Then `year` "1905" Java read is 2003.0
`Month` 01 Java read 2.0
`Boolean` false in excell Java read String.

Finally `spam -1` ...

Comment: For the `-1` part , the sheet is considered to have 20 rows with only 3 rows populated, so you get a column count -1 for the other 17 empty rows. Also double-check the data in your file, or create a new one and re-test .

Comment: and the incorrect data?

Comment: For the data, that's why I suggested to double-check the content of your file or create a new one, there is no way that 1905 gets converted once to 1995 and once to 2003.Chances are that you are dealing with the wrong file.

Comment: The file doesn't incorrect because I can read "Eduu" eduu4 " chemita " etc... If I put in excell ALL inputs format "text" Java can read correctly.